# Using ezplot with parameter of function grater than 0 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphic

So, I have a function `f = x^2` where `x` is a symbol and I want to draw the graphic of it. How can I say to matlab that I want my `x` to be grater than `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html):

```
ezplot('x^2',[0 10]) % or whatever interval you want to specify
```